# How to remove domain of a websites on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the dataset

```
Id  Websites
1   facebook.com
2   linked.in
3   stackoverflow.com
4   harvard.edu
5   ugm.ac.id
```

Heres's my expected output

```
Id  Name
1   facebook
2   linked
3   stackoverflow
4   harvard
5   ugm
```

Comment: what is the domain was `meta.stackoverflow.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to get the part before the first dot, combined with `pop` to remove the Website column:

```
df['Name'] = df.pop('Websites').str.extract('([^.]+)')
```

output:

```
   Id           Name
0   1       facebook
1   2         linked
2   3  stackoverflow
3   4        harvard
4   5            ugm
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the string also includes a sub-domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the name by "." and take what appears before the first `.`

```
df['Names'] = df['Websites'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

Output:

```
Id  Websites              Names
1   facebook.com          facebook
2   linked.in             linked 
3   stackoverflow.com     stackoverflow
4   harvard.edu           harvard
5   ugm.ac.id             ugm
```

Answer (score 1):

Can make use of rsplit to split by the last occurrence of ".". Next part will be extracting out the domain name. Such that when cases like <abc.cde.com> occurs, it will return <abc.cde>

```
df['Name'].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[0]
```